# Estructura de datos AVLTree

Tags: java

Mi pregunta es, teniendo una estructura de datos AVLTree<Par<Mascota, ArrayList<ArrayList>> denominada datos, como puedo añadir a 'datos' un ArrayList.

La clase es la siguiente:

```html
public class Cliente {
    private final String nombre;
    private final AVLTree<Par<Mascota, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> data;

    public Cliente(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre.trim().toLowerCase();
        this.data = new AVLTree<>();
    }

    public boolean addMascota(String nombre, String especie) {
        Par<Mascota, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> mascotaAux = new Par<>(new Mascota(nombre, especie), new ArrayList<>());
        Par<Mascota, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> mascotaCurr = this.data.find(mascotaAux);
       
        if(this.data.contains(mascotaCurr)) return false;
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        //...
    }
```

El método addMascota lo que hace es que sí ya existe el par con el nombre y especie en 'datos' devuelve false, en caso contrario, añade a datos un nuevo par.